# Please can I get some help to install my Canon TS6350 printer scanner on 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, scanner, canon

I am a complete novice with Linux (Ubuntu 20.04).  I am in my first few days with Linux so I have zero relevant skills.

I installed 20.04 on a new mini PC HISTTON i7-8559U and everything seems to work except I am having difficulties installing the Canon TS6350 printer/scanner which is connected via a USB cable. The printing side prints a test page OK but the scanner `Document Scan` in `Utilities` does not make the scanner work. `Document Scan` knows the hardware exists (as it correctly shows the name Canon TS6350) but when I click on `scan` I get a message `"cannot connect to scanner"`.

Any help and advice will be gratefully received but please consider my total lack of experience. Thanks.

Comment: Underneath where it says `Ready to Scan` is there a drop down that lists the printers? If so, have you tried a different selection?

Comment: Thanks. Have just tried your suggestion. There was one (only) alternative in the list, "ESCL TS6300 series". I selected it and tried again. First time it did not work and gave the same error message as before but on a second attempt (and a third) it worked and offered me a pdf file to save and that worked fine. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: Shall I post that as an answer for you to accept?

Answer (score 0):

Underneath where it says `Ready to Scan` there is a drop down that lists the available printers (in this case an HP Printer).

[image]

Select a printer from the drop down (retry if necessary) and (in the case of the OP) it offered a pdf file to save and it worked thereafter.